# Resolve in Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my angular sample route , I am trying to do :

```
(function(angular){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('appRouter',['ui.router'])
        .controller('routerCtrl',function(myResolveServ,resolveData){
            console.log(resolveData);

        })
        .service('myResolveServ',function($http){
            this.getResolveData = function($http){
                var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                return $http.get(root+'/posts/1').then(function(response){

                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        })
        .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
            $stateProvider
                .state('settings.profile',{
                    url:'/profile',
                    templateUrl:'templates/profile.html'
                })
                .state('settings.account',{
                    url:'/account',
                    templateUrl:'templates/account.html',
                    controller:'routerCtrl',
                    controllerAs:'vm',
                    resolve:{
                        resolveData :function(myResolveServ){
                            var data = myResolveServ.getResolveData();
                        }
                    }
                });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/settings/profile');  


        });

})(window.angular);
```

But this code does not work. I am not able to navigate to Accounts Page URL 
`/settings/account`.

Error is not obvious in console.

What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

I know this works:

```
                resolve:{
                     resolveData : function($http){
                         var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
                         return $http.get(root+'/posts/1').then(function(response){

                             return response.data;
                         });
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: You say 'going to the URL /settings/account' - where is that exactly? settings.account is the state, which has a URL of /account, so which one is /settings/account?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return data in your resolve for route `settings.account`

```
 resolveData: function(myResolveServ) {
    return myResolveServ.getResolveData();
 }
```

Comment: I tried , but it is not logging in console that's happening in controller.

Comment: Not working. Does the service seem ok ? Should the controller be logging the data ?

Comment: hard to say...if there's no errors logged on the console usually it's just the resolve not returning anything which causes the controller to hang and no view to render...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why, you should watch ui router errors.
Paste the code below and look for the error

```
var $rootScope = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("#home")[0]).injector().get('$rootScope');

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  console.log('$stateChangeStart to '+toState.to+'- fired when the transition begins. toState,toParams : \n',toState, toParams);
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  console.log('$stateChangeError - fired when an error occurs during transition.');
  console.log(arguments);
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log('$stateChangeSuccess to '+toState.name+'- fired once the state transition is complete.');
});

$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(event){
  console.log('$viewContentLoaded - fired after dom rendered',event);
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
console.log('$stateNotFound '+unfoundState.to+'  - fired when a state cannot be found by its name.');
  console.log(unfoundState, fromState, fromParams);
});`
```